# Why is my Tie::IxHash program taking a long time?

Tags: perl, optimization, hash

Basically, I have a script to create a hash for COGs with corresponding gene IDs:

```
# Open directory and get all the files in it
opendir(DIR, "/my/path/to/COG/");
my @infiles = grep(/OG-.*\.fasta/, readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);

# Create hash for COGs and their corresponding gene IDs
tie my %ids_for, 'Tie::IxHash';

if (! -e '/my/path/to/COG/COG_hash.ref') {
    for my $infile (@infiles) {
        ## $infile
        %ids_for = (%ids_for, read_COG_fasta($infile));
    }
    ## %ids_for
    store \%ids_for, '/my/path/to/COG/COG_hash.ref';
}

my $id_ref = retrieve('/my/path/to/COG/COG_hash.ref');
%ids_for = %$id_ref;
## %ids_for
```

The problem isn't that it doesn't work (at least I think), but that it is extremely slow for some reason. When I tried to test run it, it would take weeks for me to have an actual result. Somehow the hash creation is really really slow and I'm sure there is some way to optimize it better for it to work way faster.

Ideally, the paths should be the input of the script that way there would be no need to constantly change the script in case the path changes.

It would also be great if there could be a way to see the progress of the hash creation, like maybe have it show that it is 25% done, 50% done, 75% done and ultimately 100% done. Regarding this last point I have seen things like `use Term::ProgressBar` but I am not sure if it would be appropriate in this case.

Comment: Do you need to use `Tie::IxHash`? That will make working with your hash slower by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really need `Tie::IxHash`?

That aside, I suspect your culprit is this set of lines:

```
for my $infile (@infiles) {
    ## $infile
    %ids_for = (%ids_for, read_COG_fasta($infile));
}
```

To add a key to the hash, you are creating a list of the current key-value pairs, adding the new pair, then assigning it all back to the hash.

What happens if you take the results from `read_COG_fasta` and add the keys one at a time?

```
for my $infile (@infiles) {
    my %new_hash = read_COG_fasta($infile);
    foreach my $key ( keys %new_hash ) {
        $ids_for{$key} = $new_hash{$key};
        }
}
```

As for progress, I usually have something like this when I'm trying to figure out something:

```
use v5.26;

my $file_count = @files;
foreach my $n ( 0 .. $#files ) {
    say "[$n/$file_count] Processing $file[$n]";
    my %result = ...;
    printf "\tGot %d results", scalar %hash; # v5.26 feature!
    }
```

You could do the same sort of thing with the keys that you get back so you can track the size.

Comment: How do you know `read_COG_fasta` just retuns a single key-value pair?

Comment: I would have suggested `my %new_hash = read_COG_fasta($infile); @ids_for{keys %new_hash} = values %new_hash;`.   But either way, this is going to muddle the ordering of keys returned by each single read_COG_fasta call.  If that is a concern, %new_hash should also be tied.  Or, much better would be to pass a reference to read_COG_fasta and just have it add to the hash.

Comment: Thanks for your comments ! I will try your modifications and see how it goes ! I will keep you posted !

Comment: Update on the script: I tried running it without Ti::IxHash as it is actually not that very important and it seems to have fixed. What was taken days is not only taking roughly 30 minutes ! That said, the modification to the script and the addition of the progress is also very useful and I appreciate your answer! Thanks again for the help !